# How do I restart Docker containers on Windows reboot?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

It may sound like a known issue but the problem is that when system reboots, the containers don't start and appear to be in the Exited status. We're using docker-compose to start up the containers (in total about ~10 containers launched as a PowerShell script).

The docker documentation says to use the restart_policy but that mainly deals with container crashes. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file.
The restart always flag is also set in the config file and doesn't seem to help, have tried setting up the task scheduler however it's still the same issue.

I'm wondering if there's a way the containers will be started gracefully or if it could be set up in Task Scheduler?

Comment: are them windows or linux containers?

Comment: all of them are windows containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create and schedule task to stop the containers at system startup first and create another task to schedule an event on the successful completion of the previous task.

The important thing for another task is to edit the new event filter in XML format and to update the original task upon the successful completion of which we want to trigger a new task.

```
<QueryList>
<Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
<Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler'] and Task = 102]]</Select>
</Query>
</QueryList>
```

You need to edit query manually and to replace the following line in the XML filter:

```
*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler'] and Task = 102]]
```

with:

```
*[EventData [@Name='TaskSuccessEvent'][Data[@Name='TaskName']='\Original\Task']]
```

The event filter details for the new task are as follows:

```
Events Logs: Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational
Event source: TaskScheduler
Task category: Task completed (status 102)
```

The event ID of the original task with the completion status code id 102:

```
EventID: 102
Provider-Name: Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler
Channel: Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational
TaskName: \Original\Task
```

Finally, add the action details with the program executable path and script/command (passing it as the argument) and save your changes to be able to run with the highest privileges.